# How do I dynamically create cached assets that allow browser cacheing in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have a web application that uses .js files filled with data to drive the front-end.  These files can be large, so I want the browser to cache them.  They are static data available to all the users, so I also want to have them page cached, as their creation can be time consuming.

The data that drives them changes at random intervals at the back end.  Thus, when the data changes, I want to invalidate the server page cache AND the user's browser cache, causing a refresh.

The application also has a large # of static assets and we use the asset pipeline with precompilation to provide them in production (no dynamic compilation).

How can I page cache these files so they get served quickly to all users without hitting the full Rails stack, and browser cache... yet also invalidate both when necessary to update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's so easy as

```
javascript_include_tag 'jquery.js', 'jquery-ui.js', :cache => 'cached/all'
```

Take a look at [**Rails API about caching**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) and the [**Jammit gem**](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) could be usefull also.

Comment: I think that works for static files -- but if the file changes while the app is running, I don't think that will work.  Will it?

Comment: The caching it's defined at Rack level so it will re-cache the files if a change is detected, although that shouldn't be an issue in production mode.